# Should I use 'is' or 'are' in this sentence? which one is correct?

Tags: collective-nouns

You can't trust people with secrets these days. The majority [is or are] gossips. which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use "are" treating the sentence as an elided from of

> The majority of people are gossips.

"majority" takes plural forms. Not all collective nouns do:

> - The army is ready to march. (not are ready)
> - The orchestra is tuning up.
> - The middle-class are going to benefit from this law.
> - The Senate is going to pass the law. (Bu the Senators had to be pushed into doing so.)
> - The Yuppies enjoy services delivered to their doors.

There doesn't seem to be a clear rule on which collective nouns take plural forms.